# Spanable String color Results Black Color

Tags: android, colors

Does any one guide me that why resulted `String` from `Spanable` using user defined color in color.xml are not resulting the Expected result 
below is the Sample Code

```
    sorry_Span=new SpannableString("Sorry, you dont have any registered device, what you want to do ?");
    sorry_Span.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 36, 42, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    //sorry_Span.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(R.color.blue_txt), 36, 42, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    sorry_Msg.setText(sorry_Span);
```

When run with the `Color.Blue` it results fine 
but when run with the `R.color.blue_txt` it blanks that text 
Thanks in advance for help

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So I found the answer at my own using this hope this can help somebody who may want to use custom color

```
    sorry_Span=new SpannableString("Sorry, you dont have any registered device, what you want to do ?");
    sorry_Span.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 36, 42, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    //sorry_Span.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(R.color.blue_txt), 36, 42, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    sorry_Msg.setText(sorry_Span);
```

the custom colors can be handled with the following Method

```
Color.rgb(int red,int green,int blue)
```

so with the use of this i make my own custom colr as following

```
    sorry_Span=new SpannableString("Sorry, you dont have any registered device, what you want to do ?");

   // sorry_Span.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.rgb(34,141,65), 36, 42, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
sorry_Span.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(getResource().getColor(R.color.mycolor), 36, 42, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    sorry_Msg.setText(sorry_Span);
```

Answer (score 5):

your color XML should look like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<resources>
    <color name="blue_color">#ff0000FF</color>    
</resources>
```

Edit:
Change to this:

```
sorry_Span.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_txt)), 36, 42, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Answer (score 0):

getContext().getColor(R.color.black);
Now its deprecated since android 6.0 (API 22+)

ContextCompat is a class for replacing some work with base context

```
    val wordTwo: Spannable = SpannableString("Your new message")

    wordTwo.setSpan(
        ForegroundColorSpan(ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), R.color.red)),
        0,
        wordTwo.length,
        Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
    )
```